# inserting html into getElementById("id").innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I changing HTML near the top of my website using JS and its not working I was having a similar problem earlier because the quotations were messing it up but i tried to fix it with that method but it still isn't working.

```js
document.getElementById("accTabs").innerHTML = "<a onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" id="log"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> SIGN IN</a>";
```

Comment: What was the error message in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("accTabs").innerHTML = "<a onclick=\"document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'\" class=\"w3-bar-item w3-button\" id=\"log\"><i class=\"fas fa-users\"></i> SIGN IN</a>";
```

```html
<div id="accTabs"></div>
```

Please try like this snippet.
Your error is raised because you used quote incorrectly.

```
document.getElementById("accTabs").innerHTML = "<a onclick="alert('ok')"></a>";
```

If you try like this code, then double quote inside double quote will cause the problem.
You need to change this like below to escape the problem

```
document.getElementById("accTbs").innerHTML = "<a onclick=\"alert('ok')\"></a>";
```

> You could also use ES6 template literal. then you can use double quote and single quote inside string without any problem.

```
document.getElementById("accTabs").innerHTML = `<a onclick="alert('ok')"></a>`;
```

Comment: welcome~ You could upvote and check as right answer if this helpful.

Comment: Using template strings is the easiest way, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("accTabs").innerHTML = "<a onclick=\" document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'\" class=\"w3-bar-item w3-button\" id=\"log\"><i class=\"fas fa-users\"></i> SIGN IN</a>";
```

```html
<div id="accTabs"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using **template strings** as shown below

```
document.getElementById("accTabs").innerHTML = `<a 
onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-bar- 
item w3-button" id="log"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> SIGN IN</a>`;
```

This would work.
Learn more about Templete strings [Here](http://wesbos.com/template-strings-html/)

Answer (score 0):

Just properly escape your `"` with `\"` and use `'` to wrap the string, reducing escapes

```js
document.getElementById("accTabs").innerHTML = '<a onclick="document.getElementById(\'id01\').style.display=\'block\'" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" id="log"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> SIGN IN</a>';
```

```html
<div id="accTabs"></div>
<div id="id01" style="display: inline">id01</span>
```

Moreover, you could also try ES6's backtick ` to even completely avoid escaping.

```js
document.getElementById("accTabs").innerHTML = `<a onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" id="log"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> SIGN IN</a>`;
```

```html
<div id="accTabs"></div>
<div id="id01" style="display: inline">id01</span>
```